# Code execution shell vs Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, powershell, jupyter-notebook

I have a general question regarding code execution. I have a case when the same code is executed perfectly in shell and has some issues in Jupiter.

In Jupyter Notebook it tends to stop, usually at the beginning of the loop or before user input. Nothing happens then but the kernel is busy. Same part of the code sometimes works and sometimes doesn't.

Program is very simple so that should not be an issue. Have you ever faced similar issues? Can it be because I haven't split the code into few cells? Many thanks in advance!

EDIT: I've added the full code as I haven't managed to re-create a problem on a smaller sample. Basically the problem occurs either at the very start of the game when hit_or_stand should be executed or at the repeat_game() function level.

```
# import
import random

# define classes

deck_colors = ["Hearts", "Spades", "Clubs", "Diamonds"]
deck_ranks = ["Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"]
deck_values = {"Two" : 2, "Three" : 3, "Four" : 4, "Five" : 5, "Six" : 6, "Seven" : 7, "Eight" : 8, "Nine" : 9,
            "Ten" : 10, "Jack" : 10, "Queen" : 10, "King" : 10, "Ace" : 11}

class Card():    

    def __init__(self, color, rank):
        self.color = color
        self.rank = rank
        self.value = deck_values[rank]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.rank + ' of ' + self.color

class Deck():

    def __init__(self):
        self.deck = []  
        for color in deck_colors:
            for rank in deck_ranks:
                self.deck.append(Card(color, rank))

    def __str__(self):
        deck_description = ''
        for card in self.deck:
            deck_description += card.__str__() + '\n'
        return "\nCurrent deck:\n" + deck_description

    #shuffle deck before the game
    def shuffle(self):
        random.shuffle(self.deck)

    # pop last card to pass it on to players
    def pop_card(self):
        return self.deck.pop()

class Hand():

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.cards_in_hand = []
        self.value = 0
        self.aces = 0
        self.name = name

    def add_card(self, deck):
        new_card = deck.pop_card()
        self.cards_in_hand.append(new_card)
        self.value += new_card.value

        if new_card.rank == "Ace":
            self.aces += 1

        while self.aces > 0:
            if self.value > 21:
                self.value -= 10
                self.aces -=1
            else:
                break

class Chips():

    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 100
        self.bet = 0

    def take_bet(self):

        while True:
            bet_value = input(f"You have {self.value} chips. What's your bet? ")

            try:
                bet_value = int(bet_value)

                if bet_value > 0 and bet_value <= self.value:
                    self.bet = bet_value
                    self.value -= bet_value
                    break    
                elif bet_value > self.value:
                    print("You don't have enough chips.")
                    continue
                else:
                    print(f"Choose correct value (1-{self.value})")
                    continue
            except:
                print(f"You have to choose correct number (1-{self.value})!")



    def win_bet(self):
        self.value += (self.bet * 2)
        self.bet = 0

    def lose_bet(self):
        self.bet = 0

    def draw(self):
        self.value += self.bet
        self.bet = 0

# define functions

def show_some_cards(player_hand, dealer_hand):

    player_str = ''
    for card in player_hand.cards_in_hand:
        player_str += f"\n{card.__str__()} "
    print("Player's cards:", player_str)

    dealer_str = ' '
    for card in dealer_hand.cards_in_hand[1:]:
        dealer_str += f"\n{card.__str__()} "
    print("\nDealer's cards:\n<hidden card>", dealer_str)

def show_all_cards(player_hand, dealer_hand):

    player_str = ''
    for card in player_hand.cards_in_hand:
        player_str += f"\n{card.__str__()} "
    print("Player's cards:", player_str)
    print("Cards value:", player_hand.value)

    dealer_str = ' '
    for card in dealer_hand.cards_in_hand:
        dealer_str += f"\n{card.__str__()} "
    print("\nDealer's cards:", dealer_str)
    print("Cards value:", dealer_hand.value)

def hit_or_stand(player1_hand, player2_hand, deck, chips):

    global dealer_action
    global busted_before

    while True:
        print('\n'*100)
        print("Here're the cards\n")
        show_some_cards(player1_hand, player2_hand)
        action = input("Do you want another card? (Y/N)")

        if action.upper() == "Y":
            player1_hand.add_card(deck)

            if player_hand.value > 21:
                busted(player_hand, dealer_hand, chips)
                dealer_action = False
                busted_before = True
                break

            continue
        elif action.upper() == "N":
            break
        else:
            print("Choose correct answer (Y/N)")
            continue

def dealer_playing(player1_hand, player2_hand, deck, chips):

    global busted_before

    while True:
        print('\n'*100)
        print("Here're the cards\n")
        show_some_cards(player1_hand, player2_hand)

        if player2_hand.value < 17:
            player2_hand.add_card(deck)

            if player2_hand.value > 21:
                busted(dealer_hand, player_hand, chips)
                busted_before = True
                break

            continue
        else:
            break

def busted(current_hand, other_hand, chips):
    print('\n'*100)
    if current_hand.name == "Player":
        show_all_cards(current_hand, other_hand)
        chips.lose_bet()
        print(f"Player busted! You now have only {chips.value} chips.")
    elif current_hand.name == "Dealer":
        show_all_cards(other_hand, current_hand)
        chips.win_bet()
        print(f"Dealer busted! You now have {chips.value} chips.")
    else:
        print("Something went wrong! (busted function)")

def check_winners(player1_hand, player2_hand, chips):
    print('\n'*100)
    if player1_hand.value > player2_hand.value:
        show_all_cards(player1_hand, player2_hand)
        chips.win_bet()
        print(f"Player won! You now have {chips.value} chips.")
    elif player1_hand.value < player2_hand.value:
        show_all_cards(player1_hand, player2_hand)
        chips.lose_bet()
        print(f"Dealer won! You now have only {chips.value} chips.")
    elif player1_hand.value == player2_hand.value:
        show_all_cards(player1_hand, player2_hand)
        chips.draw()
        print(f"It's a draw! You still have {chips.value} chips.")

def repeat_game(chips):
    global repeat

    while True:
            repetition = input("Would you like to play again? (Y/N)")
            if chips.value > 0:
                if repetition.upper() == 'Y':
                    repeat = True
                    break    
                elif repetition.upper() == 'N':
                    repeat = False
                    break
                else:
                    print("Choose correct value (Y/N)")
                    continue
            else:
                print("You don't'have enough chips to continue.")
                repeat = False
                break

def start_again():
    global new_game

    while True:
            restart_game = input("Would you like to start completely new game? (Y/N)")

            if restart_game.upper() == 'Y':
                new_game = True
                break    
            elif restart_game.upper() == 'N':
                new_game = False
                break
            else:
                print("Choose correct value (Y/N)")
                continue

# play the game

new_game = True

while new_game == True:

    repeat = True
    player_chips = Chips()
    print("Welcome to BlackJack!")

    while repeat == True:
        print('\n'*100)
        #### initialization ###
        current_deck = Deck()
        current_deck.shuffle()
        player_hand = Hand("Player")
        player_hand.add_card(current_deck)
        player_hand.add_card(current_deck)
        dealer_hand = Hand("Dealer")
        dealer_hand.add_card(current_deck)
        dealer_hand.add_card(current_deck)

        #### game_ongoing ###

        player_chips.take_bet()
        dealer_action = True
        busted_before = False

        hit_or_stand(player_hand, dealer_hand, current_deck, player_chips)

        if dealer_action == True:
            dealer_playing(player_hand, dealer_hand, current_deck, player_chips)

        if busted_before == False:
            check_winners(player_hand, dealer_hand, player_chips)

        repeat_game(player_chips)

    start_again()
```

Answer (score 0):

Splitting the code in cells has nothing to do with the issue. Different cells are used so you won't run same code again and again. Notebook and shell have some small difference but the basic idea is same. you should share the notebook code, so, i can help you with your issue.

Comment: I've added the code. Sorry that it's so long but the problems usually occurs at the beginning as I've described it above.